# Is there a way to measure the effect of categorical factors?

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, causality, granger-causality

Assume having a dataset composed of 3 source columns and 1 results column. Here I'd like to measure the effect of A, B from source3 based on the results. However, results column is also affected by the other numerical features, like source1, source2. Is there an effective method to measure this effect of categorical features while excluding the effect of numerical features?

```
>>data
     source1 source2 source3 results
1       1       7       A       9    
2       2       8       A      11
3       3       9       B      14
4       4      10       B      16
5       5      11       B      18
```

Answer (score 1):

Running a linear regression including all three source variables will spit out a beta coefficient for `source3`. It is interpreted as the expected change in `results` as we change from `source3`'s category `A` to category `B` (or vice versa depending on software implementation), while keeping fixed the values of `source1` and `source2`. So if your data (approximately) meet the assumptions of linear regression this is seems like a nice, well-trodden path for you to choose.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more?  **step 1**: linear regression to get function f: result~source1+source2+ source3. Here, source3 is categories.  (need to covert with dummy variables, right?). **step2**: get f(B->A0 and f(A->B) results. **step3**: compare the different. right?

Comment: therefore, to generalize the solution, it actually doesn't require the assumption on linear right? We can get any model (nn, or trees, or rules) in step1, and then perfrom step2 and step3 as the same. how do you think?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite understand your notation in step2. Step 1 is to run a linear regression, Step 2 is extract the regression coefficient from the model and interpret it. In R this would be `coef(lm(results~source1+source2+source3, data = data))`. It will give you a coefficient for `source3` which is interpreted as the effect of `source3` on `results`while holding constant `source1` and `source2`. So you are controlling for the effects of those variables. This sounds like what you wanted in the OP.

Comment: Furthermore, linear regression is a well-understood modeling technique and is very interpretable. A neural network is a black box and is typically used for a prediction exercise; you're not learning as much about the effect of `source3` from a neural network. Rather you're trying to maximize the accuracy of your `results` predictions, and sacrificing interpretability in doing so

Comment: **step2** here `f(B->A)` means after having the model, we then substitute all A by B. According to the suggestion, via **coef(lm)**, we get `f=1+ 1* source1 + 2*source2 + source3B`. However, notice that from this lm model, we still can't exactly comment on the effect of source3B and source3A. are we saying `source3A` has no effect?

Comment: No. As I said in the answer above, `source3B` is "interpreted as the expected change in results as we change from source3's category A to category B". `source3A` is considered to be the reference category in this situation. Perhaps you need to do some research on how R deals with dummy variables and reference categories before you proceed further.